# Colocar duas tabelas ao lado de uma div

Tags: html

Tenho este código onde cria duas tabelas e uma div e as tabelas ficam abaixo da div:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
                </div>
            </div>
  <table border="1">
  <Legend><strong>Dias de Atendimento</strong></Legend>
  <tr>
    <th>Dia</th>
    <th>Hora</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Terça-Feira</td>
    <td>14:30 às 17:30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Quinta-Feira</td>
    <td>10:30 às 12:00</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
  <Legend><strong>Legenda</strong></Legend>
  <tr>
    <th>Cores</th>
    <th>Descrição</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vermelho</td>
    <td>Indisponível</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Amarelo</td>
    <td>Vagas (sob Consulta)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laranja</td>
    <td>Alterações</td>
  </tr>
  </table>  
        </div>
```

Pretendia colocar as tabelas ao lado da div como mostro na imagem com o quadrado vazio a vermelho ao lado da div:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara está faltando uma tag `</div>` no final do seu código! Além disso qual é a versão do Bootstrap a 3 ou 4? Vc quer apenas que fique uma tabela ao lado da outra é isso?

Comment: @hugocsl, Pretendo que as tabelas de Dias de Atendimento e Legenda fiquem ao lado do calendário, no quadrado vazio assinalado a vermelho. É a versão 3. Não falta a tag.

Comment: E não resposta que eu dei não estão?? Basta vc abrir o snippet da resposta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo que pode te ajudar. Coloquei um estilo onde é a tag do calendário apenas para te ajudar e visualizar como pode ficar.

Além de uma tag `<div>` que estava aberta sem fechar, vc tb tem alguns problemas semânticos no HTML

A tag `<legend>` está dentro da `<table>`, a tag `<legend>` deve ser usada junto com a tag  `<fieldset>` e não na tabela, te sugiro usar um  ou `<h5>` no lugar. A tag `<strong>` para colocar negrito é errado, para isso use a tag `<b>`, ou não use nenhuma delas pois a tag `H` já tem negrito por default na maioria dos browsers...

Veja um exemplo que pode te ajudar. Precisa Exibir como **"Página toda"** para ver o resultado já que vc está usando `col-lg-*`

```css
#calendar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">

    <div class="row ">

        <div class="col-lg-4 ">
            <Legend><strong>Dias de Atendimento</strong></Legend>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Dia</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Terça-Feira</td>
                    <td>14:30 às 17:30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinta-Feira</td>
                    <td>10:30 às 12:00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <Legend><strong>Legenda</strong></Legend>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Cores</th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vermelho</td>
                    <td>Indisponível</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Amarelo</td>
                    <td>Vagas (sob Consulta)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Laranja</td>
                    <td>Alterações</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
            <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```